# Apache Display An Index of / In Place of Default Page?

Tags: apache-http-server

Has anyone here managed to get FancyIndexing working in Apache 2.4? - I have found plenty of guides, but they are all at least 5-9 years out of date and do not work with Apache 2.4.

According to the documentation, *FancyIndexing* comes under *mod_autoindex* (which is enabled by default), and all that is required to get it working on a most basic level is **Options +Indexes** in a directory block, like so:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride None

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The problem is that it is not working: if I have a blank index page...

```
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.htm
</IfModule>
```

...the index page overrides the indexing, or:

```
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex disabled
</IfModule>
```

...causes the default Apache placeholder webpage to be displayed, as does simply removing the index page.

I should also mention that what I am trying to achieve is an index view of my web-directory in order to avoid having to implement a mess of linked pages. - The website is intended as a resource site, so visitors can simply move directly to the page or the resouce that they want with no messing around. Also, at this point, *FancyIndexing* is not absolutely essential, as I should be able to 'upgrade' to that once I have indexing working.

=======================================================================

This is additional to my comments, and is in further reply to **Anaksunaman's** answer, with my own notes and observations:

> Find the LoadModule directive for autoindex_module in httpd.conf and
>   make sure it is uncommented:
>
> LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so

Yes, I included that, as can be seen below:

```
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

> Make sure Indexes is added to your Options directive under the
>   Directory block for your DocumentRoot. In your case, your Options
>   directive appears fine e.g.:
>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

**Not quite:** there is (on Cent OS / RHEL / Red Hat / Fedora, at least) a nasty gotcha in the form of */etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf*. - The *Options -Indexes* entry needs to be amended to either *Options Indexes* or *Options +Indexes*, otherwise the indexing will not work and there will be a *client denied by server configuration: /var/www* type error in the log file.

> In httpd-autoindex.conf, make sure:
>
> Your IndexOptions directive has FancyIndexing listed e.g. IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort.
>
> Alias /icons/ is pointed at the correct directory for your icons e.g. Alias /icons/ "/path/to/Apache24/icons/"
>
> The Directory block for your icon path uses the same path as Alias /icons/ e.g

This is no longer necessary, as it is all now pre-configured (for the basic indexing and fancy indexing, at least), with an *IndexOptions* block for the addition of further configuration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

*Note that, as indicated by Y Treehugger Cymru:*

- *With the exception of Step 4 (uncommenting the entry for e.g. httpd-autoindex.conf), the items listed in each step below are generally already enabled by default, likely with correct values.*
- *The exact names and locations of the files containing each relevant entry may vary somewhat, based on your distribution of Apache (e.g. "httpd-autoindex.conf" may be "autoindex.conf", for example).*
- *Regarding Step 2, Red Hat based distributions (CentOS/RHEL/Fedora, etc.) apparently also need to have `Options -Indexes` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` changed to either `Options Indexes` or `Options +Indexes`. Otherwise, indexing apparently will not work correctly.*

---

To get `FancyIndexing` to work in Apache 2.4:

1. Find the `LoadModule` directive for [autoindex_module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) in *httpd.conf* and make sure it is uncommented:

   ```
   LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
   ```
2. Make sure `Indexes` is added to your `Options` directive under the `Directory` block for your `DocumentRoot`. In your case, your `Options` directive appears fine e.g.:

   ```
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   ```
3. Using the default `dir_module` block should be fine (you don't need to disable this) e.g.:

   ```
   <IfModule dir_module>
       DirectoryIndex index.htm
   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Look for the `Include` directive for *httpd-autoindex.conf* at the end of *httpd.conf* and make sure it is uncommented:

   ```
   Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
   ```
5. In *httpd-autoindex.conf*, make sure:

   - Your `IndexOptions` directive has `FancyIndexing` listed e.g. `IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort`.
   - `Alias /icons/` is pointed at the correct directory for your icons e.g. `Alias /icons/ "/path/to/Apache24/icons/"`
   - The `Directory` block for your icon path uses the same path as `Alias /icons/` e.g  `<Directory "/path/to/Apache24/icons/">`

Once these steps are complete, restart the server and remove/rename any index files in the directories you want to show `FancyIndexing` in.

**Example Results**

*ex. Normal Apache Indexing*

[image: No Fancy Indexing]

*ex. FancyIndex Apache Indexing*

[image: Fancy Indexing]

Comment: Thanks, - your answer was a little dated (pre-2.4), but it was well put together, with helpful observations and good examples; so I was happy to give you 2 points (or would have done, if the site had allowed me to after casting the initial vote).

Comment: In order to avoid more chaos with the website's pernicky rules, I have added further responses to your answer below my original question (my apologies if this confuses things).

Comment: Your welcome and thank you. =)  Regarding your amended question, those are definitely worthwhile observations. I honestly can't say I was aware that the Red Hat "gotcha" was even an issue... so that is a nice bit of information to have. Very much appreciated. =)